# What is this movie with a group of kids and a paper route?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching a movie a few times about a group of kids with a paper route.  The main kid is a teenager that just moved to the area.

The main scene I remember is the main kid trying to deliver a paper to an old war vet and having to use some strategy tactics to deliver it and "win" the old man's war, gaining him respect.

I remember seeing the movie somewhere between mid 90's to early 00's.  Does anyone recognize this movie?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the movie you want is [IMDB: The Paper Brigade](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117287/combined)
The reviews list all your plot elements, especially about befriending the "crazy" war vet played by
 [IMDB: Robert Englund](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000387/).
Here's an excerpt: *After the first day he decides it's too much effort until he discovers a pretty girl is on his route. The movie deals with his first love and other antics like a battle worn vet he befriends and neighborhood bullies.*